# Как правильно выстроить классы?

Tags: java, ооп

Делаю графический редактор деревьев, где имеется много типов листьев.

Поделил проект на 2 части.

- Первая содержит классы с деревом, листьями, у дерева есть методы для загрузки и сохранения в файл, эта часть ничего не знает про графический интерфейс.
- Вторая это графический интерфейc.

В графической части создал интерфейс Drawable, и тут возникает проблема, куда добавлять метод отрисовки для листьев? Хотелось бы тут просто расширить классы из первой части, не трогая ее саму, добавив реализацию методов от интерфейса Drawable, что бы можно было брать классы листьев из первой части и не заниматься конвертированием, но так вроде бы нельзя...

Comment: Расширить все же можно! https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/ExtensionMethod

Answer (score 0):

Определите один интерфейс `Drawable` для деревьев, объявите метод или методы для отрисовки в нем. Имплементируйте новый интерфейс в классах. А в графической части пишите:

```
Drawable tree = new Tree();
tree.draw();
```

ну и все в таком духе.

Если заморочиться (если много видов деревьев), посмотрите в сторону паттерна `Фабричный метод`, например.